# Create an exe file similar to executable jar file in dist folder using EXE4J

Tags: java, exe, exe4j

I wanna create an exe file that works like the executable jar file in dist folder. I tried the Regular mode in EXE4J but when i install the exe in another PC it gives me class not found error. how can i create an exe like executable jar file that uses "libs" folder for class instead adding all the jar file in one file (JAR in "exe" mode) I have searched this through internet but i could not find an answer

Comment: So, you want a "all in one" executable, so the Jar and it's dependencies are included within the executable?

Comment: No. i want exe only for executable jar file. That uses liberties in "Lib" folder.i use netbeans IDE.  hope you understand what i need. sorry if my English is not clear.

Comment: Ahh, okay, don't think it's possible that way - either it's a exe, jar and lib or it's all inclusive - it's been a while since I used exe4j

Comment: yeah. i know. all in one file is too big. executable jar file is small but not secure. that's why i needed an exe file only for executable jar file.